# Как создать такой эффект на wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Помогите создать на wpf такой дизайн авторизации...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это статичная графика? Ничего не плавает по контуру (например)?

Comment: Нет вроде) Но если плавала бы) было б, гараздо красиво)

Answer (score 7):

Держите.

Для начала, контур с glow-эффектом у нас повторяется, поэтому выделим под него отдельный контрол. У нас два входных параметра: цвет (можно использовать `Foreground`) и радиус закругления, для которого мы положим специальное Dependency Property.

Получится вот такой `UserControl`:

```
public partial class GlowFrame : UserControl
{
    public GlowFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(GlowFrame));
}
```

Теперь XAML. Мы видим на рисунке две границы: внешнюю, более размытую, и внутреннюю. Кроме того, нам нужно выделить участки под углом градусов так 30 боле сильным glow.

Для выделения участков воспользуемся `OpacityMask`. Использовать `LinearGradientBrush` как `BorderBrush` не вышло бы, т. к. у нас цвет задаётся снаружи, а вот геометрия свечения одинаковая. Затем, привязывать направление градиента OpacityMask к углам неправильно, т. к. угол будет меняться в зависимости от пропорций контрола. Поэтому положим направление градиента вертикально, и повернём на угол.

Для границ используем два `Border`'а с различным blur-размытием.

Итого:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.GlowFrame"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush  StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5" x:Key="OpacityMask">
            <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="30" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
            <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0.4"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0.6"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <Border CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}" BorderBrush="{Binding Foreground}"
                BorderThickness="10" OpacityMask="{StaticResource OpacityMask}">
            <Border.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="15" />
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
        <Border CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius}" BorderBrush="{Binding Foreground}"
                BorderThickness="3" Margin="3.5" OpacityMask="{StaticResource OpacityMask}">
            <Border.Effect>
                <BlurEffect Radius="2.5" />
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Имея это, легко сделать «табличную» разметку.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="Тест" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid Margin="30" TextBlock.FontSize="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:GlowFrame Foreground="Cyan" CornerRadius="15" Grid.RowSpan="7"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0">
                <local:GlowFrame Foreground="Violet" CornerRadius="8"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Username" Foreground="Violet" Margin="20,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="20,0">
                <local:GlowFrame Foreground="Violet" CornerRadius="8"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Password" Foreground="Violet" Margin="20,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="5" Margin="20,0">
                <local:GlowFrame Foreground="Red" CornerRadius="8"/>
                <TextBlock Text="LOGIN" Foreground="Red" Margin="20,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: красота — страшная сила]

Точные размеры и пропорции подберите сами (а также на вас стилизация `TextBox`'ов и кнопок).